# Unable to automate mouse actions using appium for mac driver

Tags: macos, appium, mouseup

i am automating a mac application using appium. I am not able to go down the in application page. i have tried couple of ways, didn't succeed.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/mouse/moveto/

when i use above option, i am not able find the element itself, but the element is very much available in page.

```
 String xpath=""/AxApplication[@AxTitle='Learning']/AXWindow/AXScrollArea[@AXDescription='My Learning']/AXList[@AXDescription='My Learning']/AXList[@AXDescription='Added by Me']/AXButton[@contains(name,'See All')]";
 Actions action = new Actions(adriver);
 WebElement elemnt=adriver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
 action.moveToElement(elemnt, 500, 900);
 action.release();
 action.perform();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: if you are using release method, press action (For eg. action.press(10, 10);) should be used in prior for drag and drop. If you are trying to mouse hover, plz remove the release statement in the above code. Also please post the error stack.